# Brave Browser and repo update

Tags: apt, thirdpartyapps

I have tried to add the repo for Brave Browser. It adds fine, but then I get this problem with it being insecure. How can I add this repo to an exceptions list? I understand apt is going to phase out using unauthenticated repos, but I have tried using the --allow-unauthenticated switch.

Comment: Did you add the PGP key to `apt` as indicated on the [site](https://brave-browser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installing-brave.html#linux)?

Comment: No he didn't because the only way he could get that error is when that happen. When `apt` can't verify the repo, and that doesn't mean that the repo is insecure is just that the user didn't follow the instructions.

Comment: i did everything on that site under ubuntu 16.04+

Comment: Then report this to brave, is their problem anyway https://github.com/brave/browser-laptop/issues | This one look like your problem exactly https://github.com/brave/brave-browser/issues/1447 | The package manager `apt` checked the signature and because didn't match didn't let you download from it. It worked like intended, the repo needs a fix. If you need a quick solution, remove the repo and then install it using `snap` like @Paul said

Answer (score 2):

**TLDR:** Uninstall and remove brave from your source, then run this on the terminal if you are using Juno.

```
curl https://brave-browser-apt-release.s3.brave.com/brave-core.asc | sudo apt-key add -

echo "deb [arch=amd64] https://brave-browser-apt-release.s3.brave.com/ bionic main" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/brave-browser-release-bionic.list

sudo apt update

sudo apt install brave-browser brave-keyring
```

---

**Why it works**

As of nov 2018, official instructions looked like this:

```
curl https://brave-browser-apt-release.s3.brave.com/brave-core.asc | sudo apt-key add -

echo "deb [arch=amd64] https://brave-browser-apt-release.s3.brave.com/ `lsb_release -sc` main" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/brave-browser-release-`lsb_release -sc`.list

sudo apt update

sudo apt install brave-browser brave-keyring
```

The command `lsb_release -sc` prints the current version of the OS, in this case `juno`. But that does not make a valid source as brave does not have that url. However, Juno is based on Ubuntu 18, codename `bionic`. So we can edit the official instructions to use that as a source.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error message as Andy when trying to install Brave via apt-get (using the same instructions on the Brave browser website)

[image]

My workaround was to install the Brave snap package:

```
sudo snap install brave
```

The Brave icon will be available in the menu after rebooting.

But as far as authorizing that repo...I have no idea.